# Google GCP error with tutorial code

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

Resolving the issue. My Case:

Before reading the question, my issue was solved due to my development environment. Using CodeKit (an application on MacOS), upon building my code from the source folder, items such as the composer.json and other files did not transfer causing the issues described below. If this does happen to you scout the two folder to look for discrepancies the paste the missing docs from the src to the build folder.

:: QUESTION ::

I am starting to use GCP today and after following the instructions defined here:

```
composer require google/cloud-storage
```

then:

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/creds.json");

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
$myid = "my-project-id";

$storage = new StorageClient([
  'projectId'=>$myid
]);

var_dump($storage->buckets());
```

When running this i get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Google\Auth\Cache\MemoryCacheItemPool' not found in /place/to/vendor/google/cloud-core/RequestWrapperTrait.php on line 94

I have no idea how to solve the issue, as i am just getting started with GCP. No idea whether this is a problem with the platform or my code.

File structure appears as follows for the Google Auth:

- vendor

  - google

    - auth

      - src
      - tests
    - cloud-core
    - cloud-storage

the **/Cache/MemoryCacheItemPool** exists inside both the tests and src folder, but the above is referencing it minus the src or tests folder.

I have also ran:

```
composer update
```

and uninstalled and reinstalled the package to no effect

[Google Cloud Project Link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you find the code that you used and pasted? Because the one present in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) is different.

This portion of code is the one in the tutorial you linked, try to use the client library and post the error logs if get any!

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;
$projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';
$storage = new StorageClient(['projectId' => $projectId]);
$bucketName = 'my-new-bucket';
$bucket = $storage->createBucket($bucketName);
echo 'Bucket ' . $bucket->name() . ' created.';
```

- Remember that bucket name should be unique and therefore I would advice you to test it with a long complex name to avoid to hit already used names, and always test the result of the operation.

**UPDATE**
I tested also your code and it is working as well, therefore I believe that is an error in the setup of the environment.

Did you get any error while running the `composer require google/cloud-storage`? Because the class that is missing `Google\Auth\Cache\MemoryCacheItemPool` is part of `Psr` that is installed by the composer

```
[...]
Installing psr/cache (1.0.1)
Loading from cache
[...]
```

**UPDATE2**
Matthew M found the error in its configuration and posted:

> Finally resolved the issue. I'm using CodeKit in my working
>   environment and it looks like it is changing something when it
>   compiles. Ran an uncompiled version and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response GalloCedrone, as you may notice in my code, it resembles yours with the addition of setting the required environmental variable. As i already have manually created a bucket, i was using `$storage->buckets();` and dumping it as a proof method, I will update my question code to resemble the updated code.

Comment: Ok! Provide as much code as possible, before I understood that you were trying to follow the documentation. Or maybe you are missing a link when you wrote: "after following the instructions defined here"

Comment: Thanks for your understanding. The code reflected in the question above now reflects everything I had written, however the error appears to be coming from calling the `StorageClient` class

Comment: And I do not understand why when you have to pass the project_id you  pass myid, that is defined as $myid = "my-bucket-id". Is it just a typo you did copying the  code here?

Comment: sorry ignore that, trying to answer someone elses ionic question on another forum, flicking back and forth constantly haha. the actual id is the ID of my project (not provided for security reasons). Code updated to reflect true code.

Comment: still fully trying to understand namespaces, so please forgive me if some of my understanding is a bit incorrect. Actually @GalloCedrone, will the fact that i am using php v5.6.32 affect things?

Comment: I tested both the portions of code (the one in the documentation and the one ) and they perfectly work on a GCE instance running PHP 7.0.27. The Php logs do not show any further information?  In which environment are you running your code(local machine, GCE instance, Linux, windows)? I guess it is a configuration issue regarding your environment.

Comment: Hi GalloCedrone. Finally resolved the issue. I'm using CodeKit in my working environment and it looks like it is changing something when it compiles. Ran an uncompiled version and it's working fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am happy to hear that you solved it, post it in the question since it can help new users stepping it into your question! Consider to accept or upvote if I have been useful, good luck!